# How to select all $refs which having particular keyword in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" ref="tenure-1">
      </div>
      <div class="col" ref="tenure-2">
      </div>
      <div class="col" ref="tenure-3">
      </div>
    </div>
```

I would like to select the refs which are all having the keyword 'tenure'. Please help me on this.

Comment: seems easy to do, this is probably not the best way but you can get all keys with Object.keys(this.$refs) then filter with .filter(n => /^tenure/.test(n) and you can go back to this.$refs to select with the resulting array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ref` is an object where "tenure-1", "tenure-2" and "tenure-3" are keys. You can just iterate over the `Object.entries(this.$refs)` and check if there are keys with a name like that.

```
let keys = []
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.$refs)) {
  if (/^tenure/.test(key)) {
      keys.push({ key: value })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on the keys of the $ref object and then map it to the actual refs, I've used `.includes` in the filter but you can change it out for anything you want (like regex)

```js
Vue.component('rack', {
  props: ['ball'],
  template: '<div>{{ball}}</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted() {
    var filteredRefs = Object.keys(this.$refs).filter((ref) => {
      if(ref.includes('tenure')){
      return true
      }
      return false
    }).map((val) => { return this.$refs[val]})
    console.log(filteredRefs)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" ref="tenure-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col" ref="tenure-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col" ref="tenure-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col" ref="not">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```